# PHP Stripe get the transaction id after successful purchase

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment

I'm trying to get the transaction ID after the purchase, but it returns empty on thankyou page

order.php

```
<?php
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('<test token>');

$amount = 100;
$card = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create a Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "source" => $card,
    "email" => $email,
    "description" => "Example description")
);

// Charge the Customer instead of the card
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $customer->id)
);

// Save the billing info
set_billing([
    'customer_id' => $customer->id,
    'address' => $address,
    'address2' => $address2,
    'city' => $city,
    'state' => $state,
    'country' => $country,
    'postal' => $postal,
    'trans_id' => $charge->id // Save the transaction id
]);

function set_billing($fields = array())
{
    $bdate = time();

    $query = "INSERT INTO billings (
        customer_id, address, address2, city,
        state, postal, country, billing_date, trans_id
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $GLOBALS['sqlConnection']->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param(
        'sssssssis', $fields['customer_id'], $fields['address'], $fields['address2'], $fields['city'], $fields['state'], $fields['postal'], $fields['country'], $bdate, $fields['trans_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}

// If successful, redirect to thank you page
header('Location: /thankyou.php?id=' . $user_id);
exit;
```

thankyou.php

```
<?php
$s = $sql->prepare('SELECT trans_id FROM billings WHERE user_id = ?');
$s->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
$s->execute();
$s->bind_result($trans_id);
$s->fetch();
?>

<ul>
    <li>Transaction id: <?php echo $trans_id ?></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: As you are fetching trans_id from billings table... In which file you are saving transaction details in billings table ?

Comment: When you charge the customer, that time you get a `message array` try printing it, and within that you'll get `transaction_id` as well. Just like `$charge_resp=$charge['msg']; $transactionid = $charge_resp->id;`

Comment: @keziah, instead of fetching the transaction id, you have to first save it as well. Where have you inserted `transaction id` in your db ?

Comment: @keziah, Lol ... You don't have both the 2 fields trans_id & user_id in billings table and in thankyou.php you are executing query using these 2 fields .... Please check your query ('SELECT trans_id FROM billings WHERE user_id = ?')

Comment: My error, but I've updated my post.

Comment: @keziah,  After editing your question please add a remark about your changes in code

Comment: I am not able to see user_id and you are using this in where clause in thankyou.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are charging the customer using this

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $customer->id)
);
```

Also try `print_r($charge); // to check the output variables`

You'll get its response as `$charge->id` this is nothing but the **transaction id**, insert this transaction id in your database for future use. And then apply your further code.

And then in **thankyou.php** fetch the value that you have inserted

Comment: @keziah, so is your issue resolved completely. if so then, Feel free to up-vote/accept if it helped anyhow or you found it useful. As it will be useful for other users as well

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use $charge->id

Update your line in order.php

```
// If successful, redirect to thank you page
header('Location: /thankyou.php?id=' . $charge->id );
```

Update your code in thankyou.php

```
<ul>
    <li>Transaction id: <?php echo $_GET['id'] ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should use $charge->id as transaction id because  balance_transaction is ID of the balance transaction that describes the impact of this charge on your account balance.

Comment: Please check this link https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-balance_transaction

Comment: I think you should not store card details on your end . You can do one thing store last 4 digits of card on your end with card id given by stripe. Stripe will manage everything on its end. You can fetch all the cards associated with user using stripe user id

Comment: You are already saving transaction details using set_billing function

Comment: Because I want the auto-fill feature when the user upgrade their account. This is will auto-fill the card number like ************4242, cvc, expiry date and billing address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113984/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-keziah).